# How to call dynamic data using list in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want this in single row and data is daynamic 
Date: 8-mar-2017
Type:Login
Source :web
IP: 192.76.0.796
Comment :ordering 
How can I get this

Answer (score 0):

Bind the data to in ItemSource to the dynamic variables